# Passing javascript to a WordPress page template?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, soundcloud

I'm working on some javascript for Soundcloud which allows the user to authenticate their account by clicking on a button and once they do this, I have it set to forward the user to a specific page. Below is the code I'm using

```
<script>
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: "MYIDHERE",
    redirect_uri: "MYURLHERE/callback.html"
  });

  $("#connect").live("click", function(){
    SC.connect(function(){
      SC.get("/me", function(me){
        $("#username").text(me.username);
        $("#userid").text(me.id);       
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "MYURLHERE/my-recordings-logged-in",
          data: {
            userID: me.id
          },
            success: function(data) {
               location.href = data;
           }
        });
      });
    });
  });

</script>
```

The issue I'm having is that when the page is forwarded to the new page, the URL has a bunch of HTML codes after it:

MYURLHERE/!DOCTYPE%20html%20PUBLIC%20"-//W3C//DTD%20XHTML%201.0%20Transitional//EN"%20" ... etc (the whole page's html code is in the actual http bar)

Instead of showing the page I created in WordPress. Not sure if this is a WordPress page template issue or if the fact that it's not forwarding to an actual .php extension?

Here's the PHP code for the page template file I'm using:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Account (Logged in)
*/
?>

<?php
require_once( 'MYURLHERE/wp-load.php' );
get_header(); ?>

    <div class="contentwrap fullwidth">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="postwrap pagefullwidth">

<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php $userid = $_POST["userID"]; ?>
        <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1000&tag=$userid'); while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View This Appreciation</a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>  

</div><!-- END postwrap -->
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- END contentwrap -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Looks like a PHP warning is coming back from the last ajax call. Can you show us the PHP that is used for that and the full warning string?

Comment: I fixed the warning & updated the html code it's spitting out now (was just editing the post when you commented)

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. You have posted PHP that looks like it creates a html page, yet the ajax is just expecting a url string. Do you just want to go to the PHP page?

Comment: The PHP is the page template for the WP page I created (my-recordings-logged-in). The javascript is on a different page (my-recordings) and when the person authenticates, I want it to send them to the logged-in page and pass the id so I can use it in the php codes to pull in specific posts that are tagged with that users id.

So I am not sending directly to a .php file, but to a URL that WP gives me for the page, and the php code is what the page-template is created with.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem with giving url. In WordPress we use `<?php bloginfo( $show ); ?>` for getting different urls. [Have a lokk at this codex section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)

My suggestion is to give the full direct url to your page like below.

```
url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/my-recordings-logged-in/"
```

Comment: Thanks Libin, but that's how I Have the direct URL in place like you mentioned and it's giving me the errors